# How to a reload a function if its execution exceeds a certain amount of time in C#?

Tags: c#, function, time, reload, sudoku

I'm trying to randomly generate a sudoku of size n.

Hence, I wrote the function : `generateSudoku(int blocksize)`

But, **this generation sometimes failed** because it's **totaly random**, and it may happends that it **generates an impossible sudoku**. I made some check functions to prevent these events.

I think there is a **50% chance** to generate a false 2x2 sudoku and when it failed, the function **runs indefinitely**.

So I would like to know if there are some functions in C# which detect that a given function **exceed a certain amount of execution time**, and if there are some functions which **can reload a function**.

For example I would like to have something like this in my code :

```
while ( generateSudoku(int blocksize).Time() > threshold ){
      generateSudoku(int blocksize).Reload()
}
```

I know it's absolutely not correct to write this, but I don't know how to explain it better.

Can you help me ? Any clues or propositions ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You aren't going to be able to do that from outside the function. What you need to do is put some code within the `generateSudoku` function so that, as it's looping it checks if too much time as passed. If it has, it returns a failure status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using threads or any kind of asynchronous logic . Effectively what you are looking for, is done code to monitor your execution and another to do your work.

If you can modify the function, the use async like this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-async-tasks-after-a-period-of-time

```
private async void MonitorCalculation(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Instantiate the CancellationTokenSource.
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    try
    {
        // ***Set up the CancellationTokenSource to cancel after 2.5 seconds. (You
        // can adjust the time.)
        cts.CancelAfter(2500);
         // I'm assuming this is your function that calculates time
        await CalculateTime(cts.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // "\r\nDownloads canceled.\r\n";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // "\r\nDownloads failed.\r\n";
    }

    cts = null;
}
```

Then in the `OperationCancelledException` you can retry or return a variable indicating that you should call again the async function.

If you can't change the calculation to async, then you can try the `TaskFactory` class.